# Flask - saving extra field after using populate_obj

Tags: python, flask, openid, wtforms, flask-login

I have a small Flask app which uses the populate.obj method for saving form data to an object.

**models.py:**

```
class User(db.DynamicDocument):
    username = db.StringField(unique=True)
    email = db.StringField(unique=True)
    role = db.IntField(default=ROLE_USER)

class Post(db.DynamicDocument):
    created_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    slug = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    comments = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))
    author = db.ReferenceField(User)

## various subclasses of BlogPost
...
```

**views.py:**

```
class Detail(MethodView):

decorators = [login_required]

# Map post types to models
class_map = {
    'post': BlogPost,
    'video': Video,
    'image': Image,
    'quote': Quote,
}

def get_context(self, slug=None):

    if slug:
        post = Post.objects.get_or_404(slug=slug)
        # Handle old posts types as well
        cls = post.__class__ if post.__class__ != Post else BlogPost
        form_cls = model_form(cls, exclude=('created_at', 'comments', 'author'))
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = form_cls(request.form, inital=post._data)
        else:
            form = form_cls(obj=post)
    else:
        # Determine which post type we need
        cls = self.class_map.get(request.args.get('type', 'post'))
        post = cls()
        form_cls = model_form(cls, exclude=('created_at', 'comments', 'author'))
        form = form_cls(request.form)
    context = {
        "post": post,
        "form": form,
        "create": slug is None
    }
    return context

    if form.validate():
        post = context.get('post')
        form.populate_obj(post)
        post.save()
```

This works fine. But what I want to do is also save the user object:

```
...
if form.validate():
    post = context.get('post')
    form.populate_obj(post)
    post(author=MyUserObject)  # this fails!
    post.save()
```

This fails with an error:

```
TypeError: 'BlogPost' object is not callable
```

I am interested to learn why this is so, and how I should save my user object? I might be demonstrating my ignorance of the `populate_obj` method here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the answer seems to be the syntax. This works:

```
  if form.validate():
        post = context.get('post')
        form.populate_obj(post)
        post.author = g.user
        post.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
if request.POST and form.validate():
    form.populate_obj(post)
    post.save()
```

Comment: Hi @codegeek. Apologies there was a typo in my code. I am trying to save the `User` object as the author in my `Post` object. So the failing line is `post(author=MyUserObject)`.

Comment: This is the code I already have. I want to save the current user object in the post as well.

Comment: sorry i guess i don't understand your question then. Are you trying to save the Post object or the User object?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to save the `Post` object. I want to add the current `User` object as the author field (see `models.Post`).